# Save web form data to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I have created a web page in c# and i am attempting to save the data from the web page to my ms database.
There are no errors in the code however it is not saving to the database, can someone take a look at this and see whats wrong please??

this is my code behind

```
    public partial class Checklist : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
      OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
      OleDbDataReader dr;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data      Source=C:\\Users\\IFMComac\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\ifm.mdb.accdb";
        cmd.Connection = conn;
     }//end of page load

    protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\IFMComac\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\ifm.mdb.accdb";
        conn.Open();

        string cmdString = ("INSERT INTO tblCheck (ChecklistID, Vehicle, Driver, WeekEnding, FuelLevel, WindscreenWasher, SteeringWheel,Brakes, Clutch, Horn, Heater, SeatBelts, WarningLights, Mirrors, Tires/Wheels, Exhaust, Lights/Reflectors, ExteriorLeaks, Body, OilLevel, CoolantLevel, Belts, EngineLeaks, LooseBolts/Screws, WarningTriangle, FireExtinguishers/FirstAidKit, AdditionalComments, CFirstName, CLastName)" + " Values (@CheckID, @Vehicle, @Driver, @WeekEnding, @FuelLevel, @WindscreenWasher, @SteeringWheel, @Brakes, @Clutch, @Horn, @Heater, @SeatBelts, @WarningLights, @Mirrors, @Tires/Wheels, @Exhaust, @Lights/Reflectors, @ExteriorLights, @Body, @OilLevel, @CoolantLevel, @Belts, @EngineLeaks, @LooseBolts/Screws, @WarningTriangle, @FireExtinguishers/FirstAidKit, @AdditionalComments, @CFirstName, @CLastName)");
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdString, conn);

        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CheckID", OleDbType.Integer, 5).Value = txtID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Vehicle", OleDbType.VarWChar, 10).Value = ddlReg;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Driver", OleDbType.VarWChar, 30).Value = ddlReg;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"WeekEnding", OleDbType.Date, 40).Value = cldDate0;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"FuelLevel", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"WindscreenWasher", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect6;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"SteeringWheel", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect11;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Brakes", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect16;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Clutch", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect21;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Horn", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect26;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Heater", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect31;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"SeatBelts" , OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect36;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"WarningLights" , OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect41;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Mirrors", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect46;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Tires/Wheels", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect51;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Exhaust", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect56;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Lights/Reflectors", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect61;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Exterior Leaks", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect66;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Body", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect71;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"OilLevel", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect76;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"CoolantLevel", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect81;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Belts", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect86;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"EngineLeaks", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect91;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"LooseBolts/Screws", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect96;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"WarningTriangle", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect101;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"FireExtinguisher/FirstAidKit", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect106;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"AdditionalComments", OleDbType.VarWChar, 100).Value = addCom;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"CFirstName", OleDbType.VarWChar, 30).Value = txtFirstName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"CLastName", OleDbType.VarWChar, 30).Value = txtLastName;


        }
        else
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

}

When i try to retrieve the data from the database it is empty. is there something missing??

Comment: what about reading some books before asking this question?

Comment: why bother to write on this if your not going to be helpful

Comment: true! but there are some many related questions around here, some many OleDb samples... so many!

Comment: yes and I have looked around and tried all different examples, so whats wrong with asking for help isnt that what these forums are for

Comment: @user3432846 to answer your last comment, this isn't a forum. Can I suggest using a try catch block in this code where there should be one anyway.

Answer (score 1):

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); statement is missing.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\IFMComac\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\ifm.mdb.accdb";

        string cmdString = ("INSERT INTO tblCheck (ChecklistID, Vehicle, Driver, WeekEnding, FuelLevel, WindscreenWasher, SteeringWheel,Brakes, Clutch, Horn, Heater, SeatBelts, WarningLights, Mirrors, Tires/Wheels, Exhaust, Lights/Reflectors, ExteriorLeaks, Body, OilLevel, CoolantLevel, Belts, EngineLeaks, LooseBolts/Screws, WarningTriangle, FireExtinguishers/FirstAidKit, AdditionalComments, CFirstName, CLastName)" + " Values (@CheckID, @Vehicle, @Driver, @WeekEnding, @FuelLevel, @WindscreenWasher, @SteeringWheel, @Brakes, @Clutch, @Horn, @Heater, @SeatBelts, @WarningLights, @Mirrors, @Tires/Wheels, @Exhaust, @Lights/Reflectors, @ExteriorLights, @Body, @OilLevel, @CoolantLevel, @Belts, @EngineLeaks, @LooseBolts/Screws, @WarningTriangle, @FireExtinguishers/FirstAidKit, @AdditionalComments, @CFirstName, @CLastName)");
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdString, conn);

        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
             conn.Open();
        }


cmd.Parameters.Add("@CheckID", OleDbType.Integer, 5).Value = txtID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Vehicle", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = ddlReg;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Driver", OleDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = ddlReg;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"WeekEnding", OleDbType.Date, 40).Value = cldDate0;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"FuelLevel", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"WindscreenWasher", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect6;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"SteeringWheel", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect11;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Brakes", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect16;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Clutch", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect21;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Horn", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect26;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Heater", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect31;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"SeatBelts" , OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect36;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"WarningLights" , OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect41;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Mirrors", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect46;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Tires/Wheels", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect51;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Exhaust", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect56;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Lights/Reflectors", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect61;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Exterior Leaks", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect66;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Body", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect71;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"OilLevel", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect76;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"CoolantLevel", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect81;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"Belts", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect86;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"EngineLeaks", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect91;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"LooseBolts/Screws", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect96;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"WarningTriangle", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect101;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"FireExtinguisher/FirstAidKit", OleDbType.Boolean, 40).Value = chkbxSelect106;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"AdditionalComments", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = addCom;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"CFirstName", OleDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txtFirstName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@"CLastName", OleDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txtLastName;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

    }
```

Without ExecuteNonQuery() your query is not executed hence your data is not saved in database.

Comment: its throwing up and error when i add ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.

Source Error: 



Line 74:                 cmd.Parameters.Add(@"CFirstName", OleDbType.VarWChar, 30).Value = txtFirstName;
Line 75:                 cmd.Parameters.Add(@"CLastName", OleDbType.VarWChar, 30).Value = txtLastName;
Line 76:                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 77:                
Line 78:             }

Comment: I prefer you to READ SOME BOOKS before starting

Comment: Change VarWChar to Varchar. take advantage of intellisence help of visual studio.